# Passing Image from Form2 to Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't pass the image in my `PictureBox` in my 2nd form into my first form which is already opened.

I'm using this code:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frmAdd = new frmAdd();

    frmAdd.pctImage.Image = pctImage.Image;

    if (btnCancel.Text == "C&OPY")
    {
        this.Close();
        return;
    }
    if (btnCancel.Text == "C&ANCEL")
    {
        this.Close();
        return;
    }
}
```

I hope someone could help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx), you should create a clone of the image when you're passing it to from one form to the other. Something like:

```
frmAdd.pctImage.Image = pctImage.Image.Clone() as Image;
```

**Edit:** As lumberjack4 pointed out, you also create a new, invisible `frmAdd` and assign your image to that form, not to the one already shown. The image may actually be correctly assigned (although you should still clone it) but it's never visible on the screen because your local `frmAdd` is never shown. Here's some code that would tell you how to do it:

In `frmAdd` ---------:

```
public partial class frmAdd : Form
{
    // Stores a reference to the currently shown frmAdd instance.
    private static frmAdd s_oInstance = null;

    // Returns the reference to the currently shown frmAdd instance
    // or null if frmAdd is not shown. Static, so other forms can
    // access this, even when an instance is not available.
    public static frmAdd Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return ( s_oInstance );
        }
    }

    public frmAdd ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    // Sets the specified picture. This is necessary because picAdd
    // is private and it's not a good idea to make it public.
    public void SetPicture ( Image oImage )
    {
        picAdd.Image = oImage;
    }

    // These event handlers are used to track if an frmAdd instance
    // is available. If yes, they update the private static reference
    // so that the instance is available to other forms.
    private void frmAdd_Load ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // Form is loaded (not necessarily visible).
        s_oInstance = this;
    }

    private void frmAdd_FormClosed ( object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e )
    {
        // Form has been closed.
        s_oInstance = null;
    }

    // Whatever other code you need
}
```

In frmNew ---------:

```
public partial class frmNew : Form
{
    public frmNew ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // Is there an active instance of frmAdd? If yes,
        // call SetPicture() with a copy of the image used by
        // this frmNew.
        frmAdd oFrm = frmAdd.Instance;

        if ( oFrm != null )
            oFrm.SetPicture ( picNew.Image.Clone () as Image );
    }
}
```

There are 2 `PictureBox` controls involved: `picAdd` on `frmAdd` and `picNew` on `frmNew`. When `btnCancel` is clicked, the code in `frmNew` checks if there's a valid `frmAdd` instance and if yes, it sets its image.

Note that `picAdd` is not a public control - it's private, as it should be. It's not a good idea to set controls to public in forms because it allows uncontrolled access to them and the form won't know their state for sure (since someone else may change those controls without the form knowing.) This can lead to vary hard-to-fix errors in larger programs.

If you need to access a control outside its form, leave the control private and create a public property/method in the form that updates the control when necessary - like the above `SetPicture` method. This still lets you assign the picture from outside the form but the form has control over how that happens because `SetPicture` can validate the image, etc. This is not possible if you just set your controls public.

Comment: What happens when you try this? Do you get an exception or just nothing is shown?

Comment: One last thing sir, can I save this image that I passed into a database?

Comment: @JamesAndrewCruz Yes, you can. You need to first save it into a `MemoryStream` and then get the bytes out of the stream. You can then write the byte array into a database. In SQL Server you'd need to use the `image` data type to store binary data.

Comment: But it requires to have a filename like you have to use a openfile dialog first? but the image that I passed does not have a filename..

Comment: @JamesAndrewCruz No, it doesn't need a filename. As long as you have an image already loaded into memory, you can just save the image into the stream and then the bytes to the DB. If your image comes from the `PictureBox`, that's fine, no need for filenames.

Answer (score 3):

```
var frmAdd = new frmAdd();
```

This line looks like you are creating a new instance of your first form `frmAdd`.  So instead of passing the image to the form that is open you are actually passing it to another, different instance.

If your second form gets created by `frmAdd`, you can add a property to the second form that references `frmAdd` then use that property to set the image.

You could have something that might look like this:

**1st Form**

```
// Just a way to launch the 2nd form
private void LaunchPictureForm()
{
    frmPicture pictureForm = new frmPicture();
    pictureForm.MyFirstForm = this;
    pictureForm.Show();
}
```

**2nd Form**

```
public frmAdd MyFirstForm { get; set; }

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyFirstForm.pctImage.Image = pctImage.Image;
}
```

Comment: I get 'NullReference Exception was unhandled'
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You need to set the reference when creating the 2nd form.  See my edit.